# Changing saved passwords in Firefox

Tags: firefox, passwords

How can I mass edit/change the same password in FireFox for multiple sites? This is necessary for intranet sites when the active directory password changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Mass Password Reset add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/9652) does just that.

> Sometimes you change a central
>   password that ends up changing 12
>   others. This add on helps you reset
>   multiple passwords in the
>   Firefox/Thunderbird password manager.

Comment: Excellent this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: This is no longer compatible with Firefox.